# EAV+Single Table Inheritance - Hydration Performance Issue - Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-attribute-value, single-table-inheritance

Currently, I am experimenting with an EAV+Single Table Inheritance approach in Doctrine 2.

I have a Base-Class that has many Values and I have multiple Sub-Classes of the Base-Class. The Sub-Classes are related.

In the following CodeExample all Entities are SubClasses of the BaseClass except for Value.

In this example the hydration takes 3200 ms:

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p', 'rip', 'rs', 'c', 'pv', 'ripv', 'rsv', 'cv')
            ->leftJoin("p.revisionsInProject", "rip")
            ->leftJoin("rip.revisionState", "rs")
            ->leftJoin("rs.component", "c")
            ->leftJoin("p.values", "pv")
            ->leftJoin("c.values", "cv")
            ->leftJoin("rs.values", "rsv")
            ->leftJoin("rip.values", "ripv")
            ->where("p.id = '".$id."'");

        $q = $qb->getQuery();

        return $q->getSingleResult();
```

In this example the hydration only takes 302 ms. The only difference is that I removed the `p.values` and the `pv` from the query.

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p', 'rip', 'rs', 'c', 'ripv', 'rsv', 'cv')
            ->leftJoin("p.revisionsInProject", "rip")
            ->leftJoin("rip.revisionState", "rs")
            ->leftJoin("rs.component", "c")
            ->leftJoin("c.values", "cv")
            ->leftJoin("rs.values", "rsv")
            ->leftJoin("rip.values", "ripv")
            ->where("p.id = '".$id."'");

        $q = $qb->getQuery();

        return $q->getSingleResult();
```

The Problem does not solved when I use other hydrations modes like `ARRAY` or `SCALAR`. They are a bit faster but still ridiculously long.

Can anybody explain why this is happening? The other values (`c.values, rs.values, rip.values`) do not significantly change the performance.

The Code itself can viewed at [Github](https://github.com/boldtrn/eav-inheritance)

Comment: The MySQL result set potentially grows exponentially for every join. Doctrine needs to iterate over every row in the result set when hydrating.

Comment: @Gerry That is obviously true, but the performance does not change that dramatically if I remove any of the other values. The `p.values` seems to have a significant impact on the querybuilder. For example if I remove the `rip.values` but keep the `p.values` the hydration takes `1000ms`. But without p.values but with rip.values the hydration is at `300ms`.

Comment: How many rows are there in the result set for both variants?

Comment: @Gerry Using the full Query it is `11340 rows` and using the Query without the p.values its `1134`. That's interesting. So my issue is the query and not the hydration.

Comment: @Gerry Do you know if there is a better way to query for the values in this example? Lazy Loading everything is no solution for me, since I need the values.

Comment: Honestly, imho EAV is something that should be avoided. There are better solutions these days, like NoSQL databases (Mongo), or if you need a mix of relational and documents, PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Gerry I tried Mongo with the same idea in, but Mongo was not suitable, since I have a lot of Relations. I should give PostgreSQL a chance, since I've never done anything with PostgreSQL. Thanks a lot Gerry.